# iOS and Swift Share Using Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, swift2

I would like to share something on Twitter. I am using the Social Framework, and I am working with Swift 2.0, and I would like to have something like this:

www.google.com TEXT
where www.google.com is A URL, i.e., when I click on it, I go to the link, while TEXT is a string. However, what I am getting is
TEXT www.google.com

I am using the following code:

```
let tweetToShare: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
tweetToShare.addURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com.ec/"))
tweetToShare.setInitialText("Miguel")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean hyperlink the TEXT to www.google.com? I think that is not possible in sharing on Twitter. You can use [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/) kind of thing if url is too long.

Good luck.